# External drive stops being recognized after waking my laptop from sleep mode

Tags: windows, windows-vista, hard-drive

Whenever my laptop wakes up from sleep mode, I'm unable to see the external drive connected to it. I've tried restarting and reconnecting the external drive, and scanning the local and external disks for issues but found no problems.

The only way to get the drive working again is by restarting the whole laptop.

Any ideas why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

**Configuration:**

- Windows Vista 32-bit
- Western Digital Essentials - 640GB external hard drive

Comment: @Schu no need to repost, a moderator will move it shortly

Answer (score 1):

Go to the windows device manager and select "universal serial bus controllers"

more than likely, you are looking for "general USB hub" and you might have more than one

you might have to test (un)plugging to find the right one (or just do it for all)

right click and go to properties, then power management

uncheck "allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"

that should do the trick!

Comment: my usb connection is already recognized as "usb mass storage device", but I dont see power options on it, though I saw them on the unused usb ports